# Save figure with clip box from another figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

Normally if you plot two different figures using the default settings in pyplot, they will be exactly the same size, and if saved can be neatly aligned in PowerPoint or the like. I'd like to generate one figure, however, which has a legend outside of the figure. The script I'm using is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,1,201)
y1=x**2
y2=np.sin(x)

fig1=plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,y1,label='y1')
handles1,labels1=plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
lgd1=plt.gca().legend(handles1,labels1,bbox_to_anchor=(1.27,1),borderaxespad=0.)

fig2=plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(x,y2)

fig1.savefig('fig1',bbox_extra_artists=(lgd1,),bbox_inches='tight')
fig2.savefig('fig2')

plt.show()
```

The problem is that in PowerPoint, I can no longer align the two figures left and have their axes aligned. Due to the use of the 'extra artists' and 'bbox_inches=tight' arguments for the first figure, the width of its margins becomes different from the second figure.

Is there any way to 'transfer' the clip box from the first figure to the second figure, such that they can be aligned by 'align left' in PowerPoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an easier way to achieve what you want is to just construct one figure with two subplots, and let matplotlib align everything for you.

Do you think doing something like this is a good idea?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.linspace(0,1,201)
y1=x**2
y2=np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure()

a = fig.add_subplot(211)

a.plot(x,y1, label='y1')

lgd1 = a.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1.27,1), borderaxespad=0.)

a = fig.add_subplot(212)
a.plot(x,y2)

fig.savefig('fig',bbox_extra_artists=(lgd1,),bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Thanks John; it had occurred to me to solve the problem in this way, but I would like to be able to use the separate figures as well. I've seen attributes like "_get_clip_box" and "_set_clip_box" in the Matplotlib docs (but without examples or a detailed description) so I believe it should be possible.